# Release Memory From TabBar Navigating To Present Tab To Another Tab Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm using tabbarcontroller as initial view controller. I noticed that when I'm changing tab(click on the another tab) the memory that it has remains and the new view memory add it to to old.

I've tried to reduce it (the memory in every tabbar) by changing all my variables to lazy and it worked for each view separately and now I don't have very high as I had to energy impact section. But the problem with views still remains (I get memory warning after a little navigation to the views).

And app also Crashed and give me error:

> terminated due to memory issue swift

**I have 5 tabs:**

`First with tableView`

`Second with collectionView and tableview`

`Third with a Camera`

`fourth with a tableView`

`And The last one 4 tableView`

From my search I understood that I have to do something with viewDidDisappear or Unload

Tabbar ScreenShot:

[image: tabbar Screen shot]

Create custom `UITabbarController` segue from storyBoard to custom navigation control:

[image: Screen Shot]

Custom navigation segue from story to first `UITabbarController` tab(Home controle):

[image: Screen Shot]

This is my Custom `UITabbar` Controller Class:

```
import UIKit

var tabBarItemCount = Int()

class CustomTabBarControl: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate 
{

@IBOutlet weak var tabBarItems: UITabBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    self.delegate = self
    statusBarStyleCheck = true
    if let items = self.tabBarItems.items {
        for i in 0..<items.count {
            items[i].tag = i
        }
    }
}


override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 4{
        boolTabProfile = true
        UserStore.shared.userIdToViewProfile = UserStore.shared.userId
      }
    }
 }
```

This is my Custom `UINavigation` Controller Class:

```
 import UIKit

 let NavigationTitleFont = "Nunito-Light"

 class CustomNavigationControl: UINavigationController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Nunito-Light", size: 16)!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:#colorLiteral(red: 0.7007879615, green: 0.6955401301, blue: 0.7298486829, alpha: 1)] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}


//Set navigation bar
var isNavigationbarHidden: Bool {
    get {
        return self.isNavigationbarHidden
    }
    set {
        isNavigationBarHidden = newValue
    }
}

//Navigation BarColor
var barColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return navigationBar.barTintColor!
    }
    set {
        navigationBar.barTintColor = newValue
    }
}

//Navigation Title Color
var navigationTitleColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return #colorLiteral(red: 0.7007879615, green: 0.6955401301, blue: 0.7298486829, alpha: 1)
    }
    set {
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Nunito-Light", size: 16)!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:newValue] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    }
}

//Hide backButton
var hidebackButton: Bool {
    get {
        return navigationItem.hidesBackButton
    }
    set {
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = newValue
    }
}

//NavigationBarImage
var navigationBarImage: UIImage? {
    get {
        return nil
    }
    set {
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(newValue, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}

//Left Navigation image
var leftNavigationCustomItem: UIImage? {
    get {
        return nil
    }
    set {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: newValue, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftNavigationItemAction(_:)))
    }
}

@objc func leftNavigationItemAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
    _ = popOrDismissViewController(true)
   }
}
```

And all 5 tab's are connected through custom navigation class.

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your code doing when you click away from and then back to the same tab? Are you instantiating a new view controller every time, or showing the already instantiated view controller?

Comment: check if there is any chance of "retain cycle", specially review your code if you using blocks, clouser , delegate or any strong variable, which is not able to release memory.

Comment: Yes @MikeTaverne Every time instantiating a new view controller i  update my question please check

Comment: @guru yes i am change all variable strong to weak and yes i am using delegate method

Comment: but i don't know how to check or release delegate variable memory

Comment: if you are using custom delegate then it should be always weak.

Comment: ya i m using custom delegate but how to solve memory issue ?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Any solution

Comment: The problem is probably not in the view controllers themselves, but in the data they hold. Tab bar controller is supposed to hold the references to the view controllers, associated with relevant tabs (so you probably should not create a new one when the user navigates to a tab he previously visited), but the view controllers are responsible for releasing any data that can be released when they disappear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply 
again my question How ?

Comment: because i am new in ios so help me

Comment: Please share you code, without it no one can help , as it depends on how you creating object and handle it.

Comment: Please share the code for your UITabBarController, specifically what it does when a tab bar button is touched.

Comment: @guru please check again

Comment: @MikeTaverne please check again

Comment: initially your code looks good, i can't find any problem with your tabBar or navigationBar. the issue is different. its may be related to you viewcontroller.